# Kafka Streams / Reduce and log retention

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a question about log retention and Kafka Streams reduce operations...

I have a following stream configuration...

```
builder.
 .stream("topic1", Comsumed.with(Serdes.string(), Serdes.string()))
 .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.string(), Serdes.string()))
.reduce((val1, val2) -> val2, Materialzed.as("store1"))
```

I know tombstone events are not reaching the reduce function, so I have to use special object signalling the delete but how it works if the log retention deletes a message, how can transfer this to MaterializedView?

Answer (score 1):

If you read a topic as a stream, and log retention truncates the topic, you cannot to get informed about this.

> Personal note: I think what you are doing is an anti-pattern. And the issues you are hitting, is an indicator for this.

The only way to get "delete" events from a topic is, if you use a compacted topic and read it as a `KTable`. Deletes there only happens via tombstones that the `KTable` will receive and process those accordingly.

Comment: I don't know it is an anti-pattern, we have this topic, that several stream configurations running, one is the one you see, reduce the stream and converts to a KTable, the other stream on the same topic, aggregate values. The trick is, we set the log retention to 7 days and expected that the aggregation contains only the values from last 7 days, which can only happen if during log retention a delete event is triggered....if this is not working this way then I have to window the stream to 7 days and then let the aggregate function run I think.

Comment: I have another question then about MaterializedView size in RockDB if it does not get events from log retention, it increases indefinitely? A Key disappears from topic because of retention but stays in RockDB forever? So log size stays small but RockDB grows and grows?

Comment: Yes, you can aggregate a stream into a table, but this does not imply that the table is updated when data in the stream input topic is truncated due to retention. Thus, your expectation is too strong -- this is not not the system works. -- About unbounded grows: yes, if your key space over time is unbounded, your RocksDB state would grow unbounded, too. -- As you mentioned, if you assume that keys are deleted eventually (due to retention) using a windowing approach would solve this issue.